# Sendmail not relaying to 127.0.0.1:25 instead of smart host

Tags: sendmail, rhel7, smarthost

I am trying to use a SMART_HOST on RHEL7 with sendmail. I have configured sendmail.mc as follows:

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `my.relay.com')dnl
```

After compiling I have this line in sendmail.cf:

```
# "Smart" relay host (may be null)
DS[my.relay.com]
```

So it seems to have accepted it. Restarted sendmail service. When sending a test mail, I find the following in the log and no mail arrives (obviously):

```
Apr 24 11:27:13 myhost sendmail[51939]: 13O9RDBi051939: to=webmaster@myhost.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30008, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (13O9RDpv051940 Message accepted for delivery)
```

For some reason it still relays to **relay=[127.0.0.1]** and I can't figure out the reason after sheer endless research. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** you use sendmail (by sendmail.org) command to send email **THEN** messages are passed to local sendmail daemon listening at 127.0.0.1:25.
It was introduced ib sendmail-8.12 to avoid installation as set root id program.   It had been huge security risk.

Your smart host configuration in sendmail.cf should affect next hop.

Comment: Where could I continue to troubleshoot then? Mails are not delivered. To my understanding sendmail should use the SMART_HOST and this should also reflect in the log.

Comment: There should be TWO pairs of from= to= log entries.  You may locate second pair by its queue-id reported in to= line of the first pair (`13O9RDpv051940`)

Comment: `Apr 25 10:04:28 myhost sendmail[121754]: 13P84Ss8121754: from=myuser, size=23, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202104250804.13P84Ss8121754@myhost.com>, relay=root@localhost
Apr 25 10:04:28 myhost sendmail[121754]: 13P84Ss8121754: to=someuser@realdomain.com, ctladdr=myuser (1001/1001), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30023, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown`

Comment: `Apr 25 10:04:28 myhost sendmail[121754]: 13P84Ss8121754: 13P84Ss9121754: DSN: User unknown
Apr 25 10:04:28 myhost sendmail[121754]: 13P84Ss9121754: to=myuser, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31047, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (13P84S2N121755 Message accepted for delivery)`

Comment: As root execute the two tests commands below: 1. `echo 3,0 'someuser@realdomain.com' | sendmail -bt` 2. `sendmail -bv 'someuser@realdomain.com'` .  They quite likely will provide extra hints (They trace delivery selection)